# Getting No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm having the following error when trying to hit my webapi code from another site.

Here's the json message being returned.

```
    "Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 
'http://localhost:47845/api/Test?samAccountName=aasdf&success=True&permissionName=bla'.","MessageDetail":
"No action was found on the controller 'Test' that matches the request."
```

When I hit the site directly, 
http://MyServer/ApiToHit/api/Values?samAccountName=someAccount&success=True&permissionName=MyPermission

I get a nice success string.

When I hit it with the following code, I get the error message above.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = true }))
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


                var values = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(string.Format(
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PathToParameters"].ToString(),
                    "someAccount".ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                    true.ToString(),
                    "MyPermission".ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));

                lblResult.Text = string.Empty;

                var newUrl = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Url"].ToString() + values);

                // HTTP GET
                var response = await client.GetAsync(newUrl, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(false);
                //var response = await client.GetAsync(values, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(false);
                this.lblResult.Text = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
```

Here's my api controller

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    // GET: api/Test
    public string Get(string samAccountName, bool success, string permissionName)
    {
        var returnValue = "Success";

        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Here's my route

```
  public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );


        }
    }

public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Comment: Shouldn't your `RouteConfig` have a `MapRoute` for the `TestController` ? What you've shown above is only for the `HomeController`.

Comment: Show your route configuration for Web API. it is usually in `WebApiConfig.cs`

Comment: I've added the webApiConfig.cs value (it's just the default one).  I also added a bit more information since in dev this works fine but it's only in our production environment that it doesn't work properly.

Comment: Have you tried it through fiddler? , Good to always explicitly stating the accepted HTTP method, [HttpGet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this I figured out the issue with this.
I got some of the error messages mixed up through the day.

The above error was fixed because the issue with the encoding of the parameters of the call to the web.config.  I had `&amp;` instead of `&` in the values >_<